# In PostgreSQL 12, Does creating partitioning via inheritance improve query performance if queries are contained with a child table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Using PostgreSQL 12, I'd like to take advantage of partitioning to 1: Aid in query performance, 2: Allow removing historic data more easily to keep mitigate database growth.

Unfortunately, declarative partitioning requires the key to be part of the PKs. A temporal field as primary key doesn't work well for my model -- so I'm exploring using inheritance instead (as per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-partitioning.html)).

My question is whether using this approach will similarly isolate the amount of rows that my SELECT statement will be exposed to if an item in my WHERE statement limits the results to a single child table.

eg.

Books => BooksJan2020, BooksFeb2020, BooksMar2020.

SELECT * FROM Books WHERE created < '01 20 2020' and author LIKE 'John%';

In declarative partitioning, I would expect the 'LIKE' statement to only be exposed to rows within the January table. Can I expect the same with inheritance? When studying how to create inherited tables, I don't see a mechanism that would tell the planner which child table to pull from.

SteveJ

Comment: I think this is exactly why one should not use inheritance for partitioning any more

Comment: @Bergi; Except that, unfortunately, partitioning is riddled with restrictions that make its use cases limited. That it must be part of the pk and that an unique constraints on pk columns must include the partition key is a primary example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by creating the appropriate check constraints on the inheritance children and leaving `constraint_exclusion` at its default value `on`.

But I want to dissuade you from using anything but declarative partitioning in v12. Partitioning by inheritance hurts. Besides, you cannot get a true primary key on anything that does not contain the partitioning key that way: even though you have a primary key on all partitions, nothing can prevent you from inserting the same key in different partitions.

My advice is to go with a primary key on `(id, created)`. True, that does not guarantee global uniqueness of `id`, but it goes a long way towards that goal. With values generated from a single sequence, the risk of duplicates is marginal.

The remaining down side of a composite primary key is that you have to include both columns into any table that has a foreign key constraint to the partitioned table, but I'd say that is the price you pay for the advantages of partitioning. Besides, with inheritance partitioning you couldn't have foreign keys pointing to the partitioned table at all.